# Is the phrase " to facilitate the comprehension of the poem" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

I want to say that the simple syntax of a poem, makes it easy for the reader to understand. Is it correct to write

> The simple syntax that is used, facilitates the comprehension of the
>   poem.

?

Comment: It's fine, except I'd delete the article: *facilitates comprehension*. ... But as a LitCrit guy I'd just as soon see this more simply expressed: "The poem's simpler syntax makes it easier to understand".

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

> **The simple syntax that is used** facilitates the comprehension of the poem.

(no comma). This seems to refer to a particular poem, since you wrote "*The* simple syntax...". Referring to poems in general, I would write:

> **Using a simple syntax** facilitates the comprehension of *a* poem.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence construction looks okay. However, you have not mentioned the easiness of comprehension that you were aiming for with the *'simplicity of the syntax'*. So you might want to add that.

> The simple syntax that is used, facilitates the **easy** comprehension of the poem.

Otherwise it looks pretty okay to me. Alternatively, you could also say :

> The use of simple syntax in the poem, facilitates its easy comprehension.